# Hide/remove '+ New Record' from 'Add Existing..' pop up dialog on Subgrid

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps, dynamic365, model-driven-app

I have a subgrid form inside a parent. I would like to hide the '+ New Record' after clicking 'Add Existing...'. Is there any way to achieve that?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could restrict the users "create" access (through their security role) to that table and only allow some users (administrators) to create new records in that table?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes removing security privilege is not a viable option and many unsupported solutions floating around in internet as well to achieve this. This is one of the long due configuration item and [idea is opened](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Ideas/Ability-to-deactivate-or-hide-the-create-new-record-from-a/idi-p/600349) as well.

Closest solution is using an available Boolean flag `isinlinenewenabled` like explained in [this blog](https://crmtipsbyprm.wordpress.com/2014/08/13/hide-new-button-on-inline-lookup-menu/). This is again debatable whether its supported.

This flag maybe available as a supported configuration item in future release but not today.